# Random Password Generator showing undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Trying to create a random password generator for a class that I am in and for the most part got everything working just fine. Except for the fact that when i try to generate a password it ends up only saying "undefined". The JS is below. Help as soon as possible would be greatly appreciated.

```
const generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");


function writePassword() {
  const password = generatePassword();
  const passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password;
}


function generatePassword() {

  let lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  let lowerArr = lower.split("");
  let upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  let upperArr = upper.split("");
  let num = "0123456789";
  let numArr = num.split("");
  let spec = "!@#$%^&*()_+?<>";
  let specArr = spec.split("");
  let allChars = [];

 
  let password = "";

  let pwlength = prompt("Choose password length: 8-128 characters.");

  if (pwlength < 8 || pwlength > 128) {
    alert("Password must be between defined length.")
    generatePassword()
  }
  if (confirm("Do you want lowercase characters?")) {
    allChars.push(lowerArr);
  }
  if (confirm("Do you want uppercase characters?")) {
    allChars.push(upperArr);
  }
  if (confirm("Do you wamt numeric characters?")) {
    allChars.push(numArr);
  }
  if (confirm("Do you want special characters?")) {
    allChars.push(specArr);
  }
  if (allChars.length === 0) {
    alert("Minimum of one type of character must be chosen");
    generatePassword()
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < pwlength; ++i) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random().length);
    password = allChars[random];
  }

  return password;
}



generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

Comment: `let random = Math.floor(Math.random().length);` - maybe you meant to work with the length of the `allChars` array? I don't think this line is doing what you expected it to do...

Answer (score 0):

At first, instead of pushing the splitted character arrays, just concat them like:

`allChars = allChars.concat(lowerArr);`

Next:

The `Math.floor()` function inside the for loop is wrong. You have to combine it with the length of the `allChars` Array and concatinate the characters to the password variable:

```
for (let i = 0; i < pwlength; ++i) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(allChars.length));
    password += allChars[random];
}
```

Comment: Definitely on the right track now, which I really do appreciate. Just now im getting something like this a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z in stead of something at random. been trying to get this to work for hours so my brain is a bit fried, i do apologize about that.

Comment: Take  a look at my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. It finally works now. Literal god send for that.